# Инструментарий для создания UI на Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-ui

Ищу различные инструменты и сервисы для облегчения работы во Flutter. А именно, что-то типа графического редактора, где я мог бы раскидать по экрану объекты, а мне вернулся бы код (не работающее приложение, а просто код описывающий позиционирование объектов). Из разряда - размещаю по центру, а мне возвращается

```
Center(child:Text('Бла-бла-бла')
```

Размещаю объект в нижней части экрана, но не по центру, а чуть сбоку - мне возвращается что-то типа

```
Align(alignment: FractionalOffset(dx,dy), child: text('бла-бла-бла'))
```

Есть ли что-то подобное? Видел подобные конструкторы для HTML, а для flutter ничего найти не смог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, подобное существует, конечно меньше, чем с JS фреймворками, но есть.

[FlutterFlow](https://flutterflow.io/) - на данный момент самый популярный сервис из подобных. Позволяет верстать экраны и экспортировать код в GitHub в последствии.
Хочу заметить, что чтобы экспортировать код оттуда, **придется приобрести премиум подписку**. Насчет удобства не скажу - не пользовался.

[FlutterViz](https://flutterviz.com/) - бесплатный аналог, также есть возможность экспорта кода. Из минусов - их продукт на данный момент в **Early Access**, то есть возможны баги (но опять же, сам не пользовался, возможно все гладко).
Также **придется сначала получить инвайт**, но это не сложно (даете имя, почту и через некоторое время присылают, если есть места, форма заявки на их сайте).

Comment: Спасибо, оба проекта хороши!

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski пожалуйста :) надеюсь подойдут под ваши задачи